# Compare two fractions

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math

How to compare $\frac{\sin{2016°}}{\sin{2017°}}$ and $\frac{\sin{2018°}}{\sin{2019°}}$?

Comment: Hint: module 360

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: @Arthur an olimpiad

Comment: And has it finished? Or is it ongoing?

Comment: @Arthur finished several years ago

Comment: Ok. The 2018 and 2019 made me think it was relatively recent.

Comment: @Arthur I think the thing was about 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$ 20176^\circ=6\cdot360^\circ-144^\circ, 2017^\circ=6\cdot360^\circ-143^\circ, 2018^\circ=6\cdot360^\circ-142^\circ, 2019^\circ=6\cdot360^\circ-141^\circ $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\frac{\sin{2016°}}{\sin{2017°}}-\frac{\sin{2018°}}{\sin{2019°}}\\
&=&\frac{\sin{144°}}{\sin{143°}}-\frac{\sin{142°}}{\sin{141°}}\\
&=&\frac{\sin{36°}}{\sin{37°}}-\frac{\sin{38°}}{\sin{39°}}\\
&=&\frac{\sin{36°}\sin{39°}-\sin{37°}\sin{38°}}{\sin{37°}\sin{39°}}\\
&=&\frac12\frac{(\cos{3°}-\cos{75°})-(\cos{1°}-\cos{75°})}{\sin{37°}\sin{39°}}\\
&=&\frac12\frac{\cos{3°}-\cos{1°}}{\sin{37°}\sin{39°}}\\
&<&0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

First, check that all these sines are **positive**, then we have: $2\sin(2017^{\circ})\sin(2019^{\circ})= \cos(2^{\circ})-\cos(4036^{\circ}), 2\sin^2(2018^{\circ})= 1-\cos(4036^{\circ})$. Since $1 > \cos(2^{\circ})$, it follows that $\sin^2(2018^{\circ})> \sin(2017^{\circ})\sin(2019^{\circ})\implies \dfrac{\sin(2017^{\circ})}{\sin(2018^{\circ})} < 
\dfrac{\sin(2018^{\circ})}{\sin(2019^{\circ})}$.

**Note 1**:  For your question, as suggested above, you should use mod $180^{\circ}$ to reduce it to an angle between $0^{\circ}$ and $180^{\circ}$ .

**Note 2**: For the **edited** problem, use the formula $\cos(a-b) - \cos(a+b) = 2\sin(a)\sin(b)$ to convert from a sine to a cosine, and it is easier to handle.

Comment: Sorry, I typed the wrong problem. Can you solve it now?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to compare ratios by taking logs:

$$
   \log \frac{\sin 2016^\circ}{\sin 2017^\circ} = \log \frac{-\sin 2016^\circ}{-\sin 2017^\circ} = \log(-\sin 2016^\circ) - \log(-\sin 2017^\circ).
$$
So we want to compare the change in $f(x)=\log(-\sin x)$ when we go from $x=2016$ to $x=2017$, versus when we go from $x=2018$ to $x=2019$.

We have $f'(x) = \cot x = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$, and $f''(x) = -\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}$, making $f$ strictly concave everywhere it is defined. (It is only defined when $\sin x$ is negative, but this holds for $1980^\circ < x < 2160^\circ$.) For concave functions, slopes are always decreasing, so we have
$$
   \log(-\sin 2017^\circ) - \log(-\sin 2016^\circ) > \log(-\sin 2019^\circ) - \log(-\sin 2018^\circ)
$$
which is equivalent to $\frac{\sin 2016^\circ}{\sin 2017^\circ} < \frac{\sin 2018^\circ}{\sin 2019^\circ}$.

You might complain that for concave functions *tangent* slopes are always negative, and that's not what we're using. To get the statement above, we could use the mean value theorem: the change $f(2017) - f(2016)$ is equal to $f'(x)$ for some $x$ between $2016$ and $2017$, and the change $f(2019) - f(2018)$ is equal to $f'(x)$ for some $x$ between $2018$ and $2019$.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use the compound angle formula:
$$\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$$
so:
$$\frac{\sin(2018)}{\sin(2017)}=\frac{\sin(2017)\cos(1)+\cos(2017)\sin(1)}{\sin(2017)}=\cos(1)+\cot(2017)\sin(1)$$
now:
$$\frac{\sin(2018)}{\sin(2019)}=\frac{\sin(2018)}{\sin(2018)\cos(1)+\cos(2018)\sin(1)}$$

Comment: Sorry, I typed the wrong problem, can you solve it now (it's fixed)